# Swapping the order of first and last names within a single column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a full name column currently formatted as firstname(s)+lastname(s). The possible variations are as follows:

```
|   Full_name        |
|--------------------|
|Jim Jones           |
|Jim Jones-Smith     |
|Jim Bob Jones       |
|Jim Bob Jones-Smith |
```

The lastname is always preceded with a space and multiple last names combined with a hyphen.

How do I swap the first and last names around with t-sql so that the result looks like this?

```
|   Full_name        |
|--------------------|
|Jones Jim           |
|Jones-Smith Jim     |
|Jones Jim Bob       |
|Jones-Smith Jim Bob |
```

Comment: Relevant reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Ideally you would never get yourself into this situation, if you want to treat two pieces of information as atomic they belong in their own columns, this is just basic relational database normalisation - with separate columns you are free to combine the data as you see fit in a query or via a computed column.

Comment: This is going to be pretty ugly in SQL Server.  I vote for dumping your table, then using Python + regex to easily make the change.

Comment: `SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE([full_name]), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE([full_name])) - 1)) + ' ' + LEFT([full_name], LEN([full_name]) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE([full_name])))`. Simplifying this, handling edge cases and/or weeping over T-SQL's feeble string handling facilities are left as exercises to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this by using last word + space + everything but the last word and filtering the edge cases manually.

```
UPDATE table SET Full_name = RIGHT(RTRIM([Full_name]),CHARINDEX(' 
',REVERSE(RTRIM(Full_name))+' ')-1) + ' ' +
SUBSTRING(Full_name, 1, LEN(Full_name) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Full_name)))
WHERE table.othercolumn NOT IN ('stuff','morestuff')
```